# Fermat's Little Theorem is applicable for any 2 Co-primes?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am confused with the results that I saw. I don't see where I am thinking wrong.

According to Fermat's Little Theorem.
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1\bmod p$$
where G.C.D(a,p) = 1 and p is prime number.

but this seems to hold for any to co-primes like

$$y^{x-1} \equiv 1\bmod x$$
where G.C.D(x,y) = 1 and x is any number.

Some Code Snippet of Python.

```
def func(x,y):
    for i in range(1,x):
        print("{0} % {1} = {2}".format(y * i ,x, (y * i)%x))
```

***Ex:***
**func(6,13)**

13 % 6 = 1

26 % 6 = 2

39 % 6 = 3

52 % 6 = 4

65 % 6 = 5

$$13 * 26 * 39 * 52 * 65 = 13^{5} * 5!$$
$$13^{5} * 5! \equiv 5! \bmod 6$$
$$13^{6-1} \equiv 1 \bmod 6$$

***Ex:***
**func(8,53)**

53 % 8 = 5

106 % 8 = 2

159 % 8 = 7

212 % 8 = 4

265 % 8 = 1

265 % 8 = 6

371 % 8 = 3

$$53 * 106 * 159 * 212 * 265 * 265 * 371 = 53^{7} * 7!$$
$$53^{7} * 7! \equiv 7! \bmod 8$$
$$53^{8-1} \equiv 1 \bmod 8$$

But in calculator i get $$53^{7} \bmod 8 = 5$$

I tried with several co-primes and ended in same conclusion.

Is it also true or I am wrong?

**Edit:**
@fleablood, Thanks for the comment.

I came to know my mistake. I need to take care of modular division.

Since I cannot divide both side by a common factor without the GCD(common_factor,N) = 1 in mod N world.

$$x^{y−1}∗(y−1)!≡(y−1)!\bmod y \nRightarrow x^{y−1}≡1 \bmod y$$

Comment: try (4,3) ------------

Comment: $x^{y-1} * (y-1)! \equiv (y-1)!\mod y \not \implies x^{y-1} \equiv 1 \mod y$.  This is *only* true if $\gcd((y-1)!, y) = 1$ which is never the case if $y$ is not prime.

Comment: $(y-1)! \equiv 0 \mod y$ if $y$ is not prime.  So $k*(y-1)! \equiv (y-1)!\mod y$ most certainly does *NOT* mean $k \equiv 1 \mod y$.  Not $53^7 \equiv 5 \mod 8$.

Comment: If $y = m*n$  where $1 < m,n < y$ then $(y-1)! = 1*.....*m*.....*n*.....*(y-1)$ and so $mn|(y-1)!$ so $(y-1)! \equiv 0 \mod y$.  So $x^k*(y-1)! \equiv (y-1)! \mod y$ for any composite $y$ no matter *what* $x$ and $k$ are.  This in no way implies $x^k \equiv 1$.

Answer (score 3):

No.

It's not true.
Try $3^{15} \equiv 11 \mod 16$

The correct formula is

$y^{\phi(x)}\equiv 1 \mod y$.

Where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.  If $p$ is prime then $\phi(p) = p-1$ but other wise $\phi(x) \ne x-1$.

Your mistake:

$x^{y-1} * (y-1)! \equiv (y-1)!\mod y \not \implies x^{y-1} \equiv 1 \mod y$.  This is *only* true if $\gcd((y-1)!, y) = 1$ which is never the case if $y$ is not prime.

In fact if $y$ is not prime then $(y-1)! \equiv 0 \mod y$ for pretty obvious reasons.

So so $53^7*7! \equiv 0 \equiv 7! \mod 8$

That *certainly* does not meant $53^7 \equiv 1 \mod 8$

And indeed $53^7 \equiv 5^7$ and as $\phi (8) = 4$ then $5^7 \equiv 5^3 \equiv 5 \mod 8$.

Comment: One doubt, How did you write 53^7 as 5^7.

Comment: 53=48+5.  So $53^7\5^7\mod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is given by group theory. The fact that

$$ a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p $$

follows from the fact that the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ has order $\varphi(p)=p-1$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. Therefore, any unit in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. any integer $a$ coprime with $p$) to the power $p-1$ is $1$, because $p-1$ is the order of the group.

Same applies word by word to $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ and its group of units. This group is not cyclic anymore if $N$ is not a prime number (hint: use the **Chinese Reminder Theorem** to compute this group). The order of this group of units is given by $\varphi(N)$, which you can easily compute.

In general, $\varphi(N)\neq N-1$, and this is the reason why your claim is not going to be true in general.

**Counterexample**: consider $N=15=3\cdot 5$. By the CRT we have

$$(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^{\times } \cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})^{\times } \times (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{\times }$$

Now $N-1=15-1=14$. So you want to know if every element in the previous group to the power $14$ is $1$. Without any computation, you can already see that the answer is no: consider $(1,a)$ for $a\neq 1 $ in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{\times }$. Then $a$ has order $\varphi(5)=4$. In particular, $a^{14}\neq 1$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})^{\times }$, so
$$(1,a)^{14} \neq (1,1)$$